# Update SQL statement not firing to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-update

I was wondering what am I missing here in my code. All I want to happen is to get a specific value, `creditrequest`, from `CreditRequest` table and put it in `UserData` table, `creditrequest` column. Somehow my code is not performing the task.

Here is my code:

```
using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
{
    scn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest = 
    (SELECT CAST(REPLACE(c.CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) 
    FROM CreditRequests c Where c.Username=@Username", scn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["New"];

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two statements. Try removing the next `SELECT` and then use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead.

Comment: tried removing the 2nd statement (forgot to remove it) and changed it to executenonquery. still not working @FelixPamittan

Comment: fyi, i have the same code in my other button and works perfectly fine. no idea why this one is not working

Comment: Thr structure of the parameter is as such. Cmd.paramaters.add (new sqlparamater ("@Username", the value being passed)); also as mentioned by @felix use cmd.executenonquery as no results are to be returned.

Comment: thanks @Shon. already used executenonquery, still not giving me results.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Also, your `UPDATE` statement will update all rows of `UserData`. Are you sure you're not missing another `WHERE` clause after the `SET`?

Comment: not updating the creditrequest column in database sir @FelixPamittan

Comment: Try executing `SELECT CAST(REPLACE(c.CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) 
    FROM CreditRequests c Where c.Username=@Username` directly in SSMS and see if you have have a result.

Comment: error sir Must declare the scalar variable "@Username".

Comment: You need to replace `@Username` with the value you're submitting, that is the value of `Session["New"]`

Comment: tried this in SSMS: SELECT CAST(REPLACE(c.CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) FROM CreditRequests c Where c.Username='faufao'. gives me the value of 10000 (which is the value im trying to get). but it says no column name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113471/discussion-between-paolo-duhaylungsod-and-felix-pamittan).

Comment: Also run query in SSMS `select * from userdata where username='faufao'` to make sure you have what to update. And update statement must include userdata in `from` part else you update ALL rows in your table. `UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest =     CAST(REPLACE(c.CreditRequest, ',', ''))
    FROM CreditRequests c INNER JOIN Userdata u on c.username=u.username Where c.Username=@Username`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev yes the column i want to update is there. tried the code, nothing happened sir. still not in the database

Comment: Do you mean `row` you want to update? Run `select * FROM CreditRequests c INNER JOIN Userdata u on c.username=u.username Where c.Username='faufao'` to make sure all necessary data exist in your tables.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev yes all columns are there sir. Creditrequest = 10000 (CreditRequest Table) and Creditrequest = NULL (Userdata Table)

Comment: Does the query in the previous comment return row(s)?

Comment: yes it returns the rows sir @AlexKudryashev

Comment: Run `UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest = CAST(REPLACE(c.CreditRequest, ',', '')) FROM CreditRequests c INNER JOIN Userdata u on c.username=u.username Where c.Username='faufao'` in SSMS to make sure it works.

Comment: error sir : Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.

Comment: `UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest = CAST(REPLACE(c.CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) FROM CreditRequests c INNER JOIN Userdata u on c.username=u.username Where c.Username='faufao'`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev worked sir. row is updated!

Comment: @AlexKudryashev post your answer please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let look at the code line by line.

```
using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
//I hope this is correct. Else "Server=PAOLO;Database=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security=True"
{
    scn.Open();
/*
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest = 
    (SELECT CAST(REPLACE(c.CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) 
    FROM CreditRequests c Where c.Username=@Username", scn);
*/
    //SQL statement is all wrong and can update all rows
    //Correct is
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest = "
        + "CAST(REPLACE(c.CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) "
        + " FROM CreditRequests c inner join UserData u "
        + "on c.Username=u.Username Where c.Username=@Username", scn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = (string)Session["New"]; //This is good

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```